# Identify contiguous regions in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have a large `numpy` array that I've applied a filter over. I'd like to identify the contiguous regions in this masked array. Here I'm defining a region to be contiguous if, for any index `(x1,y1)` to any other index `(x2,y2)`, they belong to the same region if there is a path of `True` values along equal integer steps along the axes (diagonals are valid steps).

That may not be as clear as a simple picture. Given the mask:

```
0010000
0100000
0110000
0000011
1000010
```

There should be three regions identified such that the output is something like

```
[ [[0,2],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2]], [[3,5],[3,6],[4,5]], [[4,0]] ]
```

I'd like to use something built into `numpy`, without resorting to writing my own [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm. A little bit of research in the docs only turned up a [1D version](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.flatnotmasked_contiguous.html#numpy.ma.flatnotmasked_contiguous) of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for `scipy.ndimage.label`, more info [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html). `label` returns an array the same shape as the input where each "unique feature has a unique value", so if you want the indices of the features you can do something like:

```
labels, numL = label(array)
label_indices = [(labels == i).nonzero() for i in xrange(1, numL+1)]
```

Comment: To include diagonals do the following: `s = ndimg.generate_binary_structure(2,2)` and then `labels, numL = ndimg.label(array, structure=s)`. For a simple and complete explanation, including customisation of the structure beyond diagonals, check: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html

Comment: Also, the next step after 'label' could be 'find_objects' of the same package. It returns a list of slices for each found "object". Using start and stop properties of a slice, brings you directly to indices.