# Efficient numpy subarrays extraction from a mask

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am searching a pythonic way to extract multiple subarrays from a given array using a mask as shown in the example:

```
a = np.array([10, 5, 3, 2, 1])
m = np.array([True, True, False, True, True])
```

The output will be a collection of array  like the following, where only the contiguous "region" of True values (True values next to each other) of the mask `m` represent the indices generating a subarray.

```
L[0] = np.array([10, 5])
L[1] = np.array([2, 1])
```

Comment: One other approach is by using scipy.ndimage.measurements.label as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440921/identify-contiguous-regions-in-2d-numpy-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def separate_regions(a, m):
    m0 = np.concatenate(( [False], m, [False] ))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(m0[1:] != m0[:-1])
    return [a[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(idx),2)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [41]: a = np.array([10, 5, 3, 2, 1])
    ...: m = np.array([True, True, False, True, True])
    ...: 

In [42]: separate_regions(a, m)
Out[42]: [array([10,  5]), array([2, 1])]
```

**Runtime test**

Other approach(es) -

```
# @kazemakase's soln
def zip_split(a, m):
    d = np.diff(m)
    cuts = np.flatnonzero(d) + 1

    asplit = np.split(a, cuts)
    msplit = np.split(m, cuts)

    L = [aseg for aseg, mseg in zip(asplit, msplit) if np.all(mseg)]
    return L
```

Timings -

```
In [49]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(100000))

In [50]: m = np.random.rand(100000)>0.2

# @kazemakase's's solution
In [51]: %timeit zip_split(a,m)
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop

# @Daniel Forsman's solution
In [52]: %timeit splitByBool(a,m)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [53]: %timeit separate_regions(a, m)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.01 ms per loop
```

Increasing the average length of islands -

```
In [58]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(100000))

In [59]: m = np.random.rand(100000)>0.1

In [60]: %timeit zip_split(a,m)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.3 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit splitByBool(a,m)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit separate_regions(a, m)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.85 ms per loop
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it provides the comparisons with the other methods discussed, furthermore a faster method. Thank you!

Comment: Fun fact: I just found out that `np.r_[False, m, False]` is 5-10x slower than `np.concatenate(([False], m, [False]))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def splitByBool(a, m):
    if m[0]:
        return np.split(a, np.nonzero(np.diff(m))[0] + 1)[::2]
    else:
        return np.split(a, np.nonzero(np.diff(m))[0] + 1)[1::2]
```

This will return a list of arrays, split into chunks of `True` in m

Comment: Nice solution. Makes use of the fact that `True` and `False` segments are necessarily alternating.

Comment: I like this solution because it can be turned into a one-liner: `np.split(a, np.nonzero(np.diff(m))[0] + 1)[1 - m[0]::2]`

Comment: Or even `np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(m)) + 1)[1 - m[0]::2)]`, which is a bit more readable

Comment: Interesting, each one liner is slower than the last :) But easier to read, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a natural application for [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

You first have to figure out where to cut the array, which is where the mask changes between `True` and `False`. Next discard all elements where the mask is `False`.

```
a = np.array([10, 5, 3, 2, 1])
m = np.array([True, True, False, True, True])

d = np.diff(m)
cuts = np.flatnonzero(d) + 1

asplit = np.split(a, cuts)
msplit = np.split(m, cuts)

L = [aseg for aseg, mseg in zip(asplit, msplit) if np.all(mseg)]

print(L[0])  # [10  5]
print(L[1])  # [2 1]
```