# Select sublists from python list, beginning and ending on the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a (very large) list similar to:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
```

and I want to extract from it a list of lists like:

```
result = [['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D']]
```

The repeating patterns can be different, for example there can also be intervals such as:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A'] (with a 'jump' over two elements)
```

I have written a very simple code that seems to work:

```
tolerance = 2
counter = 0
start, stop = 0, 0
for idx in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[idx] == a[idx+1] and counter == 0:
        start = idx
        counter += 1
    elif a[idx] == a[idx+1] and counter != 0:
        if tolerance <= 0: 
            stop = idx
        tolerance = 2
    elif a[idx] != a[idx+1]:
        tolerance -= 1
    if start != 0 and stop != 0:
        result = [a[start::stop]]
```

But 1) it is very cumbersome, 2) I need to apply this to very large lists, so is there a more concise and faster way of implementing it?

EDIT: As @Kasramvd correctly pointed out, I need the largest set that satisfies the requirement of (at most a tolerance number of jumps between the start and end elements), so I take:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'] instead of [ 'B', 'A', 'B' ]
```

because the former includes the latter.

Also it would be good if the code can select elements UP TO the certain tolerance, for example if the tolerance (maximum number of elements not equal to the start or end element) is 2, it should also return sets as:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']
```

with `tolerances` 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Would  you like to explain a little bit about the logic behind the expected output and why you don't count sets like `['B', 'A', 'B']`?

Comment: Good point, I want to extract the largest sets with the above structure that have a tolerance (jump) of at most the given one (1 or 2, or another value). So I take ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'] instead of ['B', 'A', 'B'] because the former includes the latter. 
I also realize my code was not taking this into account. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Is the pattern selected actually relevant, or do you simply inquire *how* to select a sequence following an arbitrary pattern? The pattern rules described are not really clear to me.

Comment: Why doesn't your first example return `ABABACDEDEDFGA`? Also in your last example, how is the tolerance 2 when the string has 4 letters different than A? (B,B,C,D)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , the pattern itself is not relevant. I simply need to select subintervals that start and end on the same character, and do not contain more than a given (tolerance) number of different characters inside that interval, between repetitions of the start/end character.

Comment: @TamasHegedus , in ABABACDEDEDFGA, the CDEDEDFG contains 8 instances of characters that are different from the start/end character, which in this case is A. This would be captured if the tolerance would be 8. Tolerance is the number of characters different from the start/end character, that can appear between two instances of that character. To make it clear, for a tolerance of 2 and a start character A, the string should contain:

A _ _ A _ _ A _ _ A 

where _ can stand for a character different than A or no character at all, for example AAA, ABA, ABCA but NOT ABCDA.

Comment: Does ABABABABBA match a tolerance of only 2, despite the fact that if you skip two from the first A you land on a B?

Comment: What is your metric for good *sets* of matches?  Given BCBCBABACA, is the tolerance-1 answer BCBCBAB/ACA or BCBCB/ABACA?

Comment: @DavisHerring in your example you start on a B, so you go until the last B that does not jump over a tolerance number of different elements. The result would be 

BCBCBAB and the second subset would start on an A so ACA.

Comment: If that's the case for Davis's question, you can only do it by iterating the array, as you do care about the order. By the way, are you sure your sample code correct? I just want to make a performance test but the array return nth.

Comment: @MatrixTai no, I realized the code has a problem.

Comment: Also, for Davis's question. You make contradict statements. 1. You want the longest array in OP. 2. You want first come first serve. So in tolerance = 0 (no char skipped), BCBABAB, BCB/ABAB or BC/BABAB?

Comment: @MatrixTai I don't get your question. If tolerance = 0, then you can only have AAAA, BBBBB, etc. With tolerance = 0 , you would not even detect ABA, since you skip B.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I'll try to sum it up, so please let me know if my understanding is correct: You iterate over the list from left to right. You take the element you're currently on (for example "A"), and check if there's another A within `tolerance` steps. If no, you move on to the next element in the list. If yes, you repeat the "is there another A" check until you no longer find an A. Then you append this run of A -> random letters -> A to the result. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Okay, lets say tolerance is 1 in this case. According to the question you stated (skipping the 'c', so make `deded`), so BCBABAB is BC/BABAB. But in terms you ans Davis's question. The ans will be BCB/ABAB, as checking `B` first.

Comment: Do you require a general list solution, or are elements on the list always a single character?

Comment: Are you OK with a solution that uses numpy? I.e., is your real data actually one-character strings or something that can easily be represented by a numerical code?

Comment: By the way, did you mean `a[start:stop]` instead of `a[start::stop]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution without any extra copying of lists other than the sublist results:

```
def sublists(a, tolerance):
    result = []
    index = 0

    while index < len(a):
        curr = a[index]

        for i in range(index, len(a)):
            if a[i] == curr:
                end = i
            elif i - end > tolerance:
                break

        if index != end:
            result.append(a[index:end+1])
        index += end - index + 1

    return result
```

Usage is simply as follows:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']

sublists(a, 0)  # []
sublists(a, 1)  # [['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D']]
sublists(a, 2)  # [['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D']]
```

Possible solution to extra requirement as specified in the comments:

```
if i > index and a[i] == a[i-1] == curr:
    end = i - 1
    break
elif a[i] == curr:
    end = i
elif i - end > tolerance:
    break
```

Note: I've not tested this thoroughly.

Comment: Seems to work but breaks if I feed into it my real list. The line: 

result.append(a[index:end+1])

Gives a list index out of range error. How is that not happening here, since you go beyond len(a) ?

Comment: @Qubix. Could you provide an example list in your question that would trigger an error here?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I unfortunately cannot put my real list there, because it contains confidential data, but if I just insert a print after the append line, saying : print(index, end+1) , I get end+1 to be larger than the length of the list by 1. It however works for every toy list I give it.

Comment: @Qubix. You can index past the end of a list in Python (somewhat) freely. Surely you can reproduce the error condition somehow?

Comment: Actually, if I replace end+1 with end it seems to work, but I need to test it more, to make sure I did not mess something up.

Comment: The +1 is needed in the solution to include the last character of the sublist. I'm not sure what is happening with your real list.

Comment: I have tested it and it always includes the last element without the +1. This is the clearest answer so far, so I will accept it. Thanks to everyone for your submissions, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ikkuh I know this is a bit late, but is there a way to modify the function not to take into account repetitions? For example AAABACADAAAADACADAAAA should return ABACADA, ADACADA ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include updated if/elif statements to match the new requirements. Not sure if this works for all cases.

Comment: I can't help but feel there is probably a dynamic programming solution to this that doesn't require a O(N^2) quadratic loop.

Comment: Characters found to be part of a sublist are not iterated again. Therefore I believe the two loops are more related to tolerance ≈ O(N * tolerance). With low tolerance this shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: @ikkuh Thank you very much for your update. I tried it and it seems to work, but I do have to make sure it works in every situation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to write recursively.

```
def rep_sublist(x):
    global thisrun, collection
    if len(x) == 0:
        return None
    try: # find the next value in x that is same as x[0]
        nextidx = x[1:].index(x[0])
    except ValueError: # not found, set nextidx to something larger than tol
        nextidx = tol + 1

    if nextidx <= tol: # there is repetition within tol, add to thisrun, restart at the next repetition
        thisrun += x[:nextidx+1]
        rep_sublist(x[nextidx+1:])
    else: # no rep within tol, add in the last element, restart afresh from the next element
        thisrun += x[0]
        if len(thisrun)>1:
            collection.append(thisrun)
        thisrun = []
        rep_sublist(x[1:])


tol = 2
collection = []
thisrun = []
x = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']
rep_sublist(x)
print(collection)

#[['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']]


tol = 1 # now change tolerance to 1
collection = []
thisrun = []
rep_sublist(x)
print(collection) # last sublist is shorter

#[['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']]
```

This uses global variables, it's easy wrap it into a function

Comment: Use `thisrun.extend(...)` instead of `thisrun += ...` and `del thisrun[:]` instead of `thisrun = []` to avoid needing the global declaration. `collection` appears to be fine as-is (you only call methods, but don't reassign).

Comment: How exactly can I turn all the above into a function. I tried but I get an empty list.

Comment: Awful lot of sub-list copies getting thrown around here :)

Answer (score 1):

`list.index()` actually accepts up to 3 arguments, which can make a lot of use here. You just use `l.index(item, start + 1, start + tolerance + 2)` to find the next item, and catch the `ValueError` that it raises.

```
l = list("aaa,..a/,a../a,.aaa.a,..a/,.aaa.,..aaa.,..a/.,a..a,./a.aaa.,a.a..a/.aa..a,.a/a.,a../.,a/..a..a/.a..,a/.,.a/a.")

def find_sublist(l, start, tol, found):
    # a is the value to check, i_l and i_r stand for "index_left" and "index_right", respectively
    a = l[start]
    i_l, i_r = start, start
    try:
        while True:
            i_r = l.index(a, i_r + 1, i_r + tol + 2)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if i_l < i_r:
        found.append(l[i_l:i_r + 1])
    return i_r + 1

def my_split(l)
    found = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        i = find_sublist(l, i, 2, found)

print([ "".join(s) for s in my_split(l) ])
```

Output (the join at the end is intended for illustration purposes - strings are easier to read than lists of single chars):

```
['aaa', '..', 'a/,a', '..', 'a,.aaa.a', '..', 'aaa', '.,..', 'aaa', '.,..a/.,a..a,./a.', 'aaa.,a.a..a/.aa..a,.a/a.,a', '../.', '..a..a/.a..', '.,.', 'a/a']
```

For your sample input (first block) with `tol = 2`, it gives the following result:

```
['ABABA', 'DEDED']
```

10 lines (non-blank) of main function `find_sublist` and 4 lines of usage `my_split`. I dislike recursion when plain looping does the job.

Comment: Please remove the line numbers so your answer can be pasted into an editor

Comment: why are you joining the strings at the end? The answer should be lists of 1 character strings.

Comment: @Qubix For illustration purposes. You can easily remove that join.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done. Next time I'll `:set nonumber` before copying `:)` (yep, I exposed my editor)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a **custom iterator** for this. There is no need for extensive sublist creation.

**The idea is simple**:

1. Slice the list by the step size (you referred to this as `'jump'`).
2. Run through the sliced list and check if the previous element is equal to the current one:

   - yes: remember that you currently are in a sublist and continue
   - no: check if you were in a sublist:

     - yes: you are at the end of a sublist, so `yield` the slice of the list corresponding to this sublist and continue.
     - no: just move on and keep looking

Some minor complication: You need to do this procedure for any starting index between 0 and `step`, as otherwise we miss repetition patterns of the form `l[x+i]==l[x+step+i]` for any 0 < i <`step`.

So here is how that iterator looks like:

```
def get_sec_it(a_list, step=1):                                                 
   for _start in range(step):  # this is the minor complication                                              
       prev_el = a_list[_start]  # as we compare previous and current element
       prev_idx = _start         # we store the first element here and iterate from the second on
       insec = False                                                     
       for idx in range(_start + step, len(a_list), step):  # iteration from the second element of the sliced list                   
           el = a_list[idx]  # get the element                                                  
           if el==prev_el:  # compare it with previous (step 2 first check)                                                     
               insec=True                                                      
               continue   
           # now we are in the first no of the 2. step, so 2. step - no                                                                       
           if insec:  # 2. step - no - yes:                                                         
               insec = False                                                   
               yield a_list[prev_idx: idx - step + 1]                          
           prev_el = el    # continue the iteration by                                                        
           prev_idx = idx  # updating the previous element                                                         
       if insec:  # at the very end of a slice we wont necessarily encounter an element different from the previous one                                                  
           yield a_list[prev_idx:idx+1]  # so in this case yield the sequence if we were in one.l
```

And here is how to user it:

```
l =['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'G']
for sec in get_sec_it(l, 2):
    print(sec)
```

Fast. Memory efficient. Easy to use.

*Le voilà, you are welcome! :)*

Comment: and you might want to replace the `range` with `xrange` if you are using python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I think this implements the sequence finding logic you want. I'm fairly sure it could be improved upon, but hopefully it's useful anyway.

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']
tol = 2
min_str_length = 2


a_str = ''.join(a)
split_char = a[0]
all_substrs = a_str.split(split_char)[1:] #First bit will be an empty string



strs_to_return = []
current_str = split_char

while len(all_substrs) != 0:
    substr = all_substrs.pop(0)
    if len(substr) <= tol and all_substrs != []:
        current_str =  current_str + substr + split_char
    elif len(substr) > tol:
        if len(current_str) > min_str_length:
            strs_to_return.append(current_str)
        #Setup the next round
        a_str = a_str[len(current_str):]
        split_char = a_str[0]
        all_substrs = a_str.split(split_char)[1:]
        current_str = split_char

if len(current_str) > min_str_length:
    strs_to_return.append(current_str)        

print(strs_to_return)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit similar to @RadhikeJCJ-

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A']
tol = 1
a_str = ''.join(a)

idx_to_split = 0
output = []
while idx_to_split < len(a_str):
    a_str = a_str[idx_to_split:]
    split_char = a_str[0]
    all_substrs = a_str.split(split_char)[1:]
    if len(all_substrs) == 1:
        idx_to_split = 1
        continue
    out = []
    for i in all_substrs:
        if i == '':
            out.append("")
        elif len(i) <= tol:
            out.append(i)
        else:
            break

    if out:
        final = split_char + '{0}'.format(split_char).join(out)
        if out[-1] != '':
            final = final + split_char
        idx_to_split = len(final)
        output.append(final)
    else:
        idx_to_split = 1

#For tolerance 2,
#output = ['ABABA', 'DEDED', 'ABAAABABACDA']

#For tolerance 1,
#output = ['ABABA', 'DEDED', 'ABAAABABA']
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the length that you want here: if len(tmp) > 2:

if you want to lenght is 5:

len(tmp) == 5 or etc...

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
start = -1
stop = -1
result = []
for i,c in enumerate(a):
    start = i
    for idx in range(i,len(a)-1,2):
        if c == a[idx]:
            stop = idx+1
        else:
            break
    tmp = a[start:stop]
    if len(tmp) == 5:
        result.append(tmp)
        print(tmp)
    start = -1
    stop = -1
print(result)
#[['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is speed and your data is easily categorizable, I would recommend a numpy solution.

Let's say you have

```
a = np.array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B'])
tolerance = 1
```

To check if any elements are equal at exactly tolerance, you can do a diff-like operation, but with equality:

```
tolerance += 1
mask = a[:-tolerance] == a[tolerance:]
```

If you smear this boolean mask `tolerance` elements to the right, each contiguous run will be the elements you are interested in. One short way to do this is using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
def smear(mask, n):
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mask, shape=(n + 1, mask.size - n),
                                           strides=mask.strides * 2)
    view[1:, view[0]] = True
```

You could even make this into a one-liner, since it operates in-place:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mask, shape=(n + 1, mask.size - n),
                                strides=mask.strides * 2)[1:, mask[:-n]] = True
```

Then you apply it:

```
smear(mask, tolerance)
```

Contiguous runs are easy to find and extract using a combination of [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) and [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) (ref):

```
result = np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(m)) + 1)[1 - m[0]::2]
```

The only thing that is lacking in this solution is that it will not pick up matching elements that occur less than `tolerance` away of each-other. To do this, we can use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to make our mask in a way that takes the tolerance into account (using [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)):

```
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(np.r_[a, np.zeros(tolerance, dtype=a.dtype)],
                                    shape=(tolerance + 1, a.size),
                                    strides=a.strides * 2)
```

`b` is now a 3x15 array (where `a` has length 15), with the second dimension just being the characters following the start. Remember that this is just a view into the original data. For a large array, this operation is basically free.

Now you can apply [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to the first dimension to figure out which characters are repeated within tolerance of each other:

```
mask = np.any(b[0] == b[1:], axis=0)
```

From here, we continue as before. This makes for a fairly small function:

**TL;DR**

```
def find_patterns(a, tol):
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    tol += 1
    b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(np.r_[a, np.zeros(tol, dtype=a.dtype)],
                                        shape=(tol + 1, a.size),
                                        strides=a.strides * 2)
    mask = np.any(b[0] == b[1:], axis=0)
    np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mask, shape=(tol + 1, mask.size - tol),
                                    strides=mask.strides * 2)[1:, mask[:-tol]] = True
    return np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(mask)) + 1)[1 - mask[0]::2]

>>> find_patterns(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B'], 1)
[array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['D', 'E', 'D', 'E', 'D'], dtype='<U1')]
>>> find_patterns(['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A'], 1)
[]
>>> find_patterns(['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A'], 2)
[array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A'], dtype='<U1')]
```

**Addendum**

If you look through the references below, you will find that the methods for smearing a mask and finding the masked portions of the array shown above here are were chosen for conciseness, not speed. A faster way to smear a mask, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728547/2988730), is:

```
def smear(mask, n):
    n += 1
    mask1 = mask.copy()
    len0, len1 = 1, 1
    while len0 + len1 < n:
        mask[len0:] |= mask1[:-len0]
        mask, mask1 = mask1, mask
        len0, len1 = len1, len0 + len1
    mask1[n - len0:] |= mask[:-n + len0]
    return mask1
```

Similarly, a faster way to extract the contiguous masked regions from the array (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43386246/2988730)) is:

```
def extract_masked(a, mask):
    mask = np.concatenate(([False], mask, [False]))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] != mask[:-1])
    return [a[idx[i]:idx[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(idx), 2)]
```

---

**References**

- [Extend numpy mask by n cells to the right for each bad value, efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32706135/2988730)
- [Efficient numpy subarrays extraction from a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43385877/2988730)